# When is using a struct more reasonable than using a class in C++?

Tags: c++

I have been reading Qt Creator's source code.
When is using a `struct` more appropriate than using a `class` in C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is purely a matter of personal preference or coding conventions. `struct` and `class` are essentially the same in C++, with the difference being the default access specifiers and base classes being `public` for a `struct` and `private` for a `class`.

For example, here two definitions of `Bar` are equivalent:

```
class Foo {};
struct Bar : Foo {};
class Bar : public Foo {};
```

Here too:

```
class Foo {};
struct Bar : private Foo {};
class Bar : Foo {};
```

and here too:

```
class Bar
{
  int n;     // private
 public:
  double x;  // public
}; 

struct Bar
{
 private:
  int n;
 public:
  double x;
};
```

Furthermore, you could forward declare `Bar` as `class Bar` or `struct Bar` interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference aside from default access (struct => public, class => private). For readability, I prefer using struct when I'm defining a plain-old C struct (just data), or when the majority of my members/methods are public.

Answer (score 1):

I think of `struct` as a record. They bundle together variables and you want to access and modify struct members without indirection, such as a function call. For example, when you want to write together groups of data items to dump them into a file or send them over network then using class may even make the code harder to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

It might be more suitable when it's Plain Old Data without any functionality on it. In C++, the only difference between `class` and `struct` is that `struct` members are `public` by default, as opposed to `private` for `class`.